# Nivo Slider JQuery problem previous picture

Tags: jquery, slider, nivo-slider

I have a small problem with Nivo Slider. I have f.e. 4 pictures (2 landscape en 2 portrait). When I fade from landscape to portrait, the last pictures stays behind the current picture.

There is a example on http://kimtesseur.no-ip.biz/vds/Verkoopstyling/Verkoopstyling.html

Is there a way to fix this?
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

From my experience using NivoSlider (quite a lot) it doesn't deal well with multiple image sizes. Best to keep them 1 size for all.

An alternative plugin to use is [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).